# HNN-extension of the orbifold fundamental group

Tags: gr.group-theory, gt.geometric-topology, orbifolds

Let $\Gamma$ be a discrete subgroup of $\operatorname{PSL}_2(\mathbb{R})$. I know that $\mathbb{H}^2/\Gamma$ has an orbifold structure. Let $\gamma$ be a non-separating closed curve. If $\Gamma$ has no torsion, we can write $\Gamma$ as an HNN-extension of the fundamental group of the complement of $\gamma$. Is there a similar result if $\Gamma$ does have torsion? Do you have any reference?

Comment: What if $\Gamma$ is finite? In any case $\Gamma$ is virtually torsion-free, and so virtually an HNN extension.

Comment: @markvs: A non-separating curve defines a dual surjection to $\mathbb{Z}$, so $\Gamma$ can't be finite.

Comment: @HJRW: Ok, but the curve lifts to a nonseparating curve in a finite cover?

Comment: @markvs: Sure, but HNN extensions in finite covers are very far from HNN extensions in the original surface. For instance, triangle orbifolds have no splittings, but most of their finite covers have infinitely many splittings.

Comment: @HJRW: So I was right that this reduces to the torsion-free case.

Comment: @markvs: No because, as the example of triangle groups makes clear, having an HNN extension of a finite-index subgroup doesn't enable you to deduce anything about splittings of the original group. That is, a "virtual HNN extension" is a much weaker object than an actual HNN extension. Otherwise, the "Virtual Haken theorem" would be the "Haken theorem"! :)

Comment: @HJRW: I was talking about virtual HNN. I know that it is weaker than HNN.

Comment: @markvs: Ah, I misunderstood your "this" above. In that case, yes, a lift of a non-separating curve to a finite-sheeted cover is always non-separating.

Answer (score 1):

A non-separating curve $\gamma$ on an orientable hyperbolic orbifold $O$ corresponds to an HNN extension of the orbifold fundamental group, just as it does in the usual case of surfaces. This is one of those "well known" things for which it may be difficult to chase down a reference. However, you could try:

> Maclachlan, C.; Harvey, W. J.
> On mapping-class groups and Teichmüller spaces.
> Proc. London Math. Soc. (3) 30 (1975), no. part, part 4, 496–512.

They prove that the mapping class group of an orbifold is equal to the mapping class group of the underlying surface (with appropriate markings for the cone points). In particular, the orbit of $\gamma$ is determined by the cut orbifold $O\setminus\gamma$. Using this, you can use a mapping class (i.e. an automorphism of $\Gamma$) to take $\gamma$ to a "standard" curve, and then read off the HNN extension from a standard presentation.